# Make button disabled by changing object property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-disabled

On button click I wan't to disable all buttons to prevent any other operation.
For this I use `request.isProcessing` bool value.
In the beginning `function approve(request)` I set `request.isProcessing` to `true` and In the end to `false`.

But this doesn't work. (For request in ng-repeat `request.isProcessing` doesn't change)

Is it because I am in different `scope` or what?

```
<div class="one-third" ng-repeat="request in pendingRequests track by request.id">
   ...
   <div class="button-container">
       <button ng-click="approve(request);" ng-disabled="request.isProcessing" class="btn btn-primary">Confirm<i ng-hide="request.isProcessing" class="fa fa-check"></i><span ng-show="request.isProcessing" class="spinner no-hover"><a><i class="fa-li fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></a></span></button>
       <button ng-click="reject(request);" ng-disabled="request.isProcessing" class="btn btn-default pull-right" am-hide-request-resolve-div>Reject <i ng-hide="request.isProcessing" class="fa fa-times"></i><span ng-show="request.isProcessing" class="spinner no-hover"><a><i class="fa-li fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></a></span></button>
   </div>
</div>

$scope.approve = function (request) {
        request.isLoading = true;
        //functionality of approving
        request.isLoading = false;
}
```

Comment: what doesn't work ? can you print {{request.isProcessing}} and check it's value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the javascript your variable is `isLoading` while in your HTML the variable is `isProcessing`. SO i guess you should rename one of them.

Comment: OMG, realy. Now it works... Now I don't know If this question shoud be on stack :D